# Excel Chart Y Axis to Rollover Back to Zero at 360

Tags: excel, vba, charts, angle

I'm trying to create an Excel chart in VBA with time on the X axis and bearing angles (from North) on the Y axis. This looks fine most of the time except where the sample of data is dealing with Northerly bearings. In this case, we might get a sample with bearing values of 000.1, 000.2, 359.9, 359.8, 000.5 etc.. The chart Y axis then stretches from 0 to 360 with data at the bottom and data at the top with a lot of empty space in between. Is there any way that the Y axis can be configured to either restart at zero when it reaches 360 or split into two so that for example, it covers the range 0 to 5 and then the range 355 to 360?
I'm simply asking whether this is feasible or not. I don't want to get too busy with coding just yet if it's a non-starter.

EDIT: - a couple of images to try and explain the problem. One image shows the sample of bearings to be around 90 degrees and it produces a nice Y axis. The second image shows the sample of bearings to be around 359-360 degrees with the odd one in the middle at 0 degrees
[image: Bearings at 90]

[image: Bearings at 360]

For the sample with Bearings around 360, I would like to be able to either "rollover" the Y axis back to 0 as it reaches 360 or have a split Y axis such that the section between 5 degrees and 355 degrees is not visible.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want the axes to change depending upon the data, but to just have fixed values. With VBA you can make both x- and y-axes fixed, the chart size fixed, etc... Is that what you mean? If yes, please be sure to provide images showing clearly exactly what you want and don't want (preferably with sample data) so you can get the help your need.

Comment: You could do a logarithmic scaled axis, it doenst handle the 0 values though.

Comment: I do want the axis to change depending on the data because the sample may be around 200 degrees or around 300 degrees etc. and in these case I would like the Y axis to automatically scale to suit. However, I get a problem if the sample of data is around 360 degrees as it flips from 360.0 to 0.0 and back again..

Comment: Can you loop the series in vba and set the y axis according to it's contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mess with your data. Suppose the times are in A2:A41 and the angles in B2:B41. Plotting columns A and B works fine unless the values are on either side of 360.

Put a test formula in E1:
=AND(MAX(B2:B41)>350,MIN(B2:B41)<10)

This tells us that some values are close to 0 and some close to 360.

Enter this formula in cell C2 and copy it down to C41:
=IF(AND($E$1,B2<10),B2+360,B2)

This adds 360 to any small value if the large values are near 360.

Finally, plot columns A vs C.

Below are two pairs of charts where I've implemented this, one not close to 360 and one close to 360.

[image: Y Axis Rollover]

Comment: This is a good idea. I hadn't though of using Y values with angles greater than 360 but the end users looking at the results are all engineers who can do the modulus without thinking. I've used VBA to make it work but it turned out simple enough. Many thanks.